# Geodjango/postgres ForeignKey relationship like a spatial index

Tags: postgresql, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship, geodjango, spatial-index

I actually looking for the best and easiest way to make a spatial index with 4 tables where the structure of data already in place.

As [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8HU4.png) show it, layer are overlayed and fit perfectly. Spatial operation could do the job in the query, but for a web GIS with heavy geoprocessing on geodjango, it's might be too heavy for a friendly use. So, adding ForeignKey relationship may work faster.

Structure is :

- L1 have many L2
- L2 have many L3
- L3 have many L4

The naming is unusual, all ID and FID are string, as :

- L1 : A,**B**,C, ... `B as exemple`
- L2 : B01, B02, **B03**, ...  `B03 exemple`
- L3 : B0301, **B0302**, B0303, ...  `B0302 exemple`
- L4 : B030201, B030202, B030203, ...

A lot of on the fly geoprocessing will occurred through this structure. That why the foreign key relation it's may be the best to do it. Finally, it's a spatial index which work with field. But how to do it?

Can I relate L1 with L2 as a rules like : where L2_FK LIKE selected_L1_ID%" instead of where L2_FK == selected_L1_ID%?

Thank

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have used spatially indexed data in this form without encountering problems using only one model/table and [django-mptt](http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/):

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey


class Region(MPTTModel):
    class Level:
        L1 = 1
        L2 = 2
        L3 = 3
        L4 = 4
        L5 = 5

        choices = (
            (L1, _("L1")),
            (L2, _("L2")),
            (L3, _("L3")),
            (L4, _("L4")),
            (L5, _("L5")),
        )

    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True,
                               related_name='children')
    layer = models.IntegerField(_('layer'), choices=Level.choices,
                                db_index=True)
    code = models.CharField(_("name"), db_index=True, max_length=100)
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(_('polygon'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code
```

(During data import, we have manually added a union of all children nodes' geoms to the parent node)